# Build failure "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64"

Tags: c++

This is my hello.cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "cat.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    speak();
    return 0;
}
```

This is my cat.h file:

```
#ifndef CAT_H_
#define CAT_H_

void speak(); 

#endif
```

and this is my cat.cpp file

```
#include "cat.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void speak(){
    cout << "yolo" << endl;
}
```

Why does it not compile? I keep getting this error:

```
undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "speak()", referenced from:
      _main in hello-9525f8.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I tried to compile it like this:
g++ hello.cpp

Comment: `g++ hello.cpp cat.cpp`.

Comment: You forgot to link the object defining the symbol.

Comment: Oh. I forgot to compile all the files. High-level languages and modern IDEs make you lazy...